# WinJS.Binding.List - key value isn't found

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winjs

I've got a WinRT/javaScript app where I use a list. As a test, I've got the following code:

```
var testList = new WinJS.Binding.List();
var item = {
    key: "mykey",
    value: "hello",
    value2: "world"
};

testList.push(item);

var foundItem = testList.getItemFromKey("mykey");
```

I would expect to be able to find my item using the key supplied; however `foundItem` always comes back undefined. Is there something I'm doing wrong in the setup and use of my list?

Also, when I examine my list at debug time, I can see that the key for the item I push is "1" instead of "mykey."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are pushing is the value of the object in the list, the key is assigned internally as a incrementing integer value.  If you crack open `base.js` in the Windows Library for JavaScript 1.0 reference in your project, you'll see the following implementation for `push`.

Note the call to `this._assignKey()`.  This value is returned to you in the [oniteminserted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh921600.aspx) handler

```
push: function (value) {
    /// <signature helpKeyword="WinJS.Binding.List.push">
    /// <summary locid="WinJS.Binding.List.push">
    /// Appends new element(s) to a list, and returns the new length of the list.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="value" type="Object" parameterArray="true" locid="WinJS.Binding.List.push_p:value">The element to insert at the end of the list.</param>
    /// <returns type="Number" integer="true" locid="WinJS.Binding.List.push_returnValue">The new length of the list.</returns>
    /// </signature>
    this._initializeKeys();
    var length = arguments.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        var item = arguments[i];
        if (this._binding) {
            item = WinJS.Binding.as(item);
        }
        var key = this._assignKey();
        this._keys.push(key);
        if (this._data) {
            this._modifyingData++;
            try {
                this._data.push(arguments[i])
            } finally {
                this._modifyingData--;
            }
        }
        this._keyMap[key] = { handle: key, key: key, data: item };
        this._notifyItemInserted(key, this._keys.length - 1, item);
    }
    return this.length;
},
```

so if you add the following to your code, you'll get the value that you could then use later (assuming you associate it with the 'key' you pushed).

```
testList.oniteminserted = function (e) {
    var newKey = e.detail.key;
};
```